# How to create symbolic link to apache document root?

Tags: apache2, symbolic-link

My apache document root locate in **/var/www** and i created a directory called **testwp** on **/var/www**. I changed some privileges

- `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/testwp`
- `sudo chmod 755 /var/www/testwp`

but i cant access that directory from my web browser `http://localhost/testwp` and it says

> 404 Not Found The requested URL /testwp was not found on this server.

How can i access like that?

can i do that? please help me. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sites-available/your-site what have you set for DocumentRoot?

Make it point to /var/www

> ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>
> ```
>     DocumentRoot /var/www
>     <Directory />
>             Options FollowSymLinks
>             AllowOverride None
>     </Directory>
>     <Directory /var/www/>
>             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>             AllowOverride None
>             Order allow,deny
>             allow from all
>     </Directory> . . .
> ```

Comment: `DocumentRoot /var/www/testwp` but it didn't work.

Comment: That's why it is not working. Change it to `/var/www`. Currently `http://localhost/testwp` refers to `/var/www/testwp/testwp` and `http://localhost` refers to `/var/www/testwp`

Comment: OMG Thank you so much for the help, it works well